# Overriding jQuery event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am trying to override the default behavior of the jQuery event handlers. But can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this.

Say I'm binding a click handler to an element like this:

```
$('div#mydiv').on('click', funcName);
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to overwrite the `.on` function, so I can modify the way any event is bound by jQuery

I've already tried overriding `$.fn.on` and that obviously caused a never ender loop:

```
$.fn.on = function(eventname, callback){
  console.log(eventname + ' will be bound');

  $(this).on(eventname, callback);
};

$(function(){
  $('#element').on('click', function(){
    console.log('Did execute click');
  });
});
```

What is the proper way to hook into the event binding process? Also worth mentioning: I really just want to alter the way `.on` works, wrapping it into a different function wouldn't work for my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `cache` the original function reference like so

```
var originalOn = jQuery.fn.on;

jQuery.fn.on = function() {
    console.log(arguments[ 0 ] + ' will be bound');

    originalOn.apply( this, arguments );
};
```

Here, we store the reference to jQuerys original `.on` function. Then we overwrite the handler, but we invoke the original function with the same *context* + *arguments* using `Function.prototype.apply`.

Comment: I would suggest to wrap this into a `(function() { ... })();` block just to make sure that `originalOn` could not be accidentally overwritten.

Comment: @t.niese in general I would agree, but I just wanted to make the point clear and show how to invoke a stored function reference correctly. I leave it to the OP to handle his application context correctly.

Comment: Sure, i just want to mention it. And it should just be seen as an addition to the answer and not as something that influences the quality of this. (I should have been clear about this)

Comment: Wow, simple and beautiful. Loving it. Thanks!